# Draw outline(courtyard) of covering all the shape of drawing

Tags: java, geometry

I want to draw an outline(courtyard) covering all the shapes of the drawing.

Currently, I can draw the outline of covering all the shapes of the drawing. But It is rectangular in shape.
I have all the properties of shapes that are in the drawing.
Below is my drawing with a rectangular shape outline.

[image: My programmed drawing]

But my requirement is to draw an outline as a reference to below's image.
The outline should be like a courtyard of drawing.
[image: Existing software drawing]

Comment: Pehaps you need somethin like `alpha shape`

Comment: Do you not have any code for us to look at?